# How to make a entity clickable which is getting generated dynamically in networked A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am using a networked A-frame to generate a new entity when the page is loaded. I want to add a few functionalities on those entities like hover, on click, etc. I tried making it clickable but it didn't work.

```js
function rigClick(){
        console.log("Entity Clicked");
      }
```

```html
<a-scene>
    <a-entity id="rig" onclick="rigClick()">
        <a-entity
          id="foo"
          networked="template:#rig-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
          camera="active:true;"
          position="-27 2.5 24"
          wasd-controls="acceleration:12;"
          look-controls
          spawn-in-circle="radius:2"
        >
        </a-entity>
     </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I also tried using the register component but I am unable to get the results.

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('click-handler', {
      init: function () {
        let entity = document.querySelector('#rig')

        entity.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log("You just clicked on entity");
        })
      }
    });
```

```html
<a-scene>
    <a-entity id="rig">
        <a-entity
          id="foo"
          networked="template:#rig-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
          camera="active:true;"
          position="-27 2.5 24"
          wasd-controls="acceleration:12;"
          look-controls
          spawn-in-circle="radius:2"
          click-handler
        >
        </a-entity>
     </a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your mouse, you need a [`cursor`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar) which will map 2D mouse clicks onto 3D rays checking whats under the mouse cursor:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
// declare a component
AFRAME.registerComponent("click-detector", {
 // called upon initialisation
 init: function() {
   // when a click is detected
   this.el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // log "clicked"
    console.log("clicked")
   })
 }
})
</script>
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: a-sphere">
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -2" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" click-detector></a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

Works the same in [aframe-networked](https://glitch.com/%7Egftruj-aframenetworked-clicks) as long as you add the component to the `networked-template` so that every new 'player' has the component attached:

```
<template id="avatar-template">
  <a-entity class="avatar">
    <a-sphere class="head" scale="0.45 0.5 0.4" click-detector></a-sphere>
  </a-entity>
</template>
```